# FFMpeg; Error when mixing two audio stream

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, video

I'm recording two stream by `ffmpeg` with this command:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist pipe,udp,rtp -fflags +genpts -f sdp -i pipe:0 \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v copy \
-filter_complex \
"[0:a:0]volume=0.5[a0]; \
 [0:a:1]volume=0.5[a1]; \
 [a0][a1]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[out]" \
-map [out] -c:a libopus \
-flags +global_header out.webm
```

that `[0:v:0]` is my video stream and `[0:a:0]` and `[0:a:1]` are my audio streams that I want to mix them up and record it associate with video stream.

But unfortunately, I get this ugly error sometimes that it causes silence in final video. I mean, when I get this error my final video becomes silence.

> LBRR frames is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the
> newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your
> file has a feature which has not been implemented.
>
> Error decoding a SILK frame.
>
> Error decoding an Opus frame.

My `ffmpeg` version is:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your `ffmpeg` is too old

Update your `ffmpeg`:

- [Download an already compiled `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)
- Or see [compile instructions at FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

This was ticket [#4641: Error decoding SILK frame](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4641). The fix is newer than the most current release branch (FFmpeg 4.3 as of writing this), so you have to get a build from the git master branch (either of the links above will do), or wait for FFmpeg 4.4.

## If you can't update

If you can't update your `ffmpeg` the old workaround is to use libopus to decode:

```
ffmpeg -c:a libopus -i input ...
```